# createMaterialTopTabNavigator: tabBarOptions not applied on android

Tags: android, react-navigation

Working on a React-Native project for Android, I added Tabs using React-Navigation. Now I'd like to apply some custom styling: a black tab background and green underlines, if the tab is active.

As suggested in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html), I used `tabBarOptions` to achieve this - but the styling does not get applied at all. I'm not able to figure out the reason for this behavior. Can you help me? Please see code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import TestScreen1 from '../../../screens/TestScreen1';
import TestScreen2 from '../../../screens/TestScreen2';

export default class TwoTabsHorizontal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.tabsView}>
        <TabLayout />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  One: {
    screen: TestScreen1,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'One',
    },
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
      },
    },
  },
  Two: {
    screen: TestScreen2,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Two',
    },
  },
});

const TabLayout = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabsView: {
    flex: 60,
  },
});
```

Despite using `tabBarOptions`, it still looks like this:

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `tabBarOptions` in the wrong place. It should be a property in the second argument to `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`. Example:

```js
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    One: {
      screen: TestScreen1,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'One',
      },
    },
    Two: {
      screen: TestScreen2,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Two',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
      },
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! :)